# std::map in a project error

Tags: c++, gcc, dictionary

I have these two files:

`Circles.h`:

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H
#include <map>
using namespace std;

map<int, int> colormap;

#endif
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Circles.h"
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
     int a;
     cin>>a;
     cout<<a<<endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Error:

> ||=== Build: Debug in Mulit-game (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZSt11__addressofISt4pairIKiN2sf5ColorEEEPT_RS5_':|
>   D:\SFML Projects\Mulit-game\main.cpp|7|multiple definition of`colormap'|
>   obj\Debug\Circles.o:c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\mingw32\bits\gthr-default.h|300|first defined here|
>   ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

I have no idea why it does this, as I've searched through all of the files of my project and the map is only found in `Circles.h`.

Comment: Please post your whole code; `colormap` is nonexistent in what you posted.

Comment: colormap is the same as stuff.

Comment: I don't know if it would make a difference here, but don't use `using namespace` in a header file. It can cause all sorts of name collisions. Use `std::map<int, int> colormap;` instead.

Comment: I've a suspicion that `Circles.h` is included in more than one source file. And with it you're getting *two* definitions for a variable with the same id. `extern` - declare it in the header and *define* it in **one** source file directly.

Comment: Nope, still the same error to Fred, that is

Comment: Notice the ...`obj\Debug\Circles.o`... in the error output. Have you got a `Circles.cpp` at all? Maybe even one that you don't need any more but which is still in your makefile? If so, does it include `Circles.h`?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming the map is actually called `colormap`, and that the header file is included in multiple source files? Because that's the only way you can get that error.

The problem is that you *define* the variable `colormap` in the header file, and so it becomes defined in each source file that includes the header.

Instead you should only make an external *declaration* in the header file, and do the definition in one source file.

---

So, in the header file do e.g.

```
extern std::map<int, int> colormap;  // Declare the colormap variable
```

And in one of your source files, at the global scope:

```
std::map<int, int> colormap;  // Define the colormap variable
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.
I was, in fact using 2 sources with Circles.h.
This really helps me out, since I need this as a global variable to update the colours of some shapes.

Comment: @Ilman you could also just put that `extern` decl in the other source file directly, but (probably) like you, If I'm declaring a type that will be used for housing a global, i prefer to just make it available by specifying said-same immediately after the type, which is what this answer provides as well. In general, avoid globals if possible in the first place, but when you need them, make them as simple to dissect as possible. In your case I would probably `typedef` the map type as well (in the header), since you're going to be using it later with iterators and such anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll typedef the map.

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare global variables in header files.

Comment: You can *declare* all the globals you want in header files; just don't *define* them there as well.

Comment: It's (usually) best not to declare or define global variables at all.

Comment: I NEED the global variable in the header file.
I know I shouldn't do it if it isn't necessary.

Comment: @Ilman: you should try not to use variables which reach across compilation units if only because it's not very clear where and how they are being used. If you only want one copy then perhaps it should be encapsulated in it's own compilation unit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your code wouldn't work. I wrote it in Visual Studio and built fine. You are using gcc compiler, which might be stricter. I would advise you not to use "using namespace std" twice in your code. To be honest, I would advice not to use "using namespace std" at all. Instead when declaring a map, do the following:

```
std::map<int,int> myMap;
```

Also, if you have a global variable (in your case colormap), it is better to declare it not in a file where you define a class (in your case Circles?).